# calculate the most repeated difference in a set of numbers algorithm

Tags: algorithm, difference

I want to calculate in a finite set of numbers the difference between them, and then take the most repeated difference. For example,
{1,2,3,6} --> Difference={1,2,5,1,4,3} --> Maximum Common diference = 1
There is an algorithm less than O(N^2)?

Comment: Most probably, there is none. You need to match every number in your collection to each other, and it takes `O(N*N)` operations.